# Laravelインストール後のドキュメントルートの設定

Tags: apache, laravel

Laravelのインストールを行いましたが、Laravelのトップ画面は、以下の細かいディレクトリで表示されています。
`http://localhost/laravel/cms/public/`
`localhost/`でLaravelトップページを表示されるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

---

＜やったこと＞

1. htdocs の中に、laravelという名前のフォルダを追加
2. エディタでこのフォルダを開く
3. ターミナルで以下のコマンドを実行
   `composer create-project laravel/laravel cms 5.5.* --prefer-dist`

---

試しに以下で設定しましたところ、 `example.com` にアクセスすると、XAMPPのダッシュボードに飛ばされてしまいます。

[XAMPPのApacheでLaravelを表示できるようにする - Qiita](https://qiita.com/hitotch/items/4f5ef016cabe040fd2a2)

Comment: Laravelはどのようにインストールしましたか？手順を明示すると回答が得られるかもしれません。

Comment: 参照されたページは「バーチャルホスト」を用いた方法です。実際の設定内容 (httpd.conf など) も含めておくと回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: htdocs の中に、laravelという名前のフォルダを追加→エディタでこのフォルダを開く→ターミナルで→composer create-project laravel/laravel cms 5.5.* --prefer-dist とコマンドを打つ

Comment: @ななみ さん、是非追記分は質問文に直接追記するようにしてみてください。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できます。コメントとして情報を追加しても1人にしか更新が通知されませんが、本文へ追記するとたくさんの人に更新されたと伝わりますし、後からこのご質問を見に来た方も読みやすいです :)

Comment: ありがとうございます！失礼いたしました！